# Gradient of a function defined with euclidean norm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

> Find the gradient of $f(x)=\|x \|^2e^{\| x^2\|}$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean 2-norm and $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$

I know that the gradient at point $p$ is defined as $\nabla f(p)= \begin {pmatrix} \partial_{x_1}f(p)  \\ \vdots \\ \partial _{x_n}f(p)\end {pmatrix}$Following with the  from the definition of the $L^2$ Norm  we have $\|x\|=\sqrt{x^2_1+x_2^2+...+x_n^2} \implies \|x\|^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2$. So if the function were $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then we would have $f'(x)=2xe^{x^2}+2x^3e^{x^2}$but I'm having trouble adapting the idea to $\mathbb{R^n}$, so far I have: $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg(\big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2\big) \exp\big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2\big)\bigg)= \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2\bigg)\exp\big( \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^2\big)+ \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2\bigg) \bigg(  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \exp\big( \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2 \big)  \bigg)   $$ But I'm not sure how to clean it all up,I thought it would be equal to $ \begin{pmatrix} 2e^{x_1^2}(x_1+x_1^3) \\ \vdots \\ 2e^{x_n^2}(x_n+x_n^3) \end {pmatrix}$ but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: The derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \lvert\lvert x \rvert\rvert^2$ is equal to $2 \, x$ . Can you go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s an alternative method. Since
$$
f(x)=g(u(x)).
$$
with
$$
g(t)=te^t,
$$
and
$$
u(x)=\|x\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2,
$$
we have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)=g’(u(x))\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(x)=2x_i(u(x)+1)e^{u(x)}.
$$
Hence
$$
\nabla f(x)=2(\|x\|^2+1)e^{\|x\|^2}x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your computation is correct so far. Continuing it, we get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 = 2x_i
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \exp\Bigl( \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 \Bigr) = 2x_i \exp\Bigl( \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 \Bigr) = 2x_i e^{\lVert x \rVert^2}.
$$
Combining the results,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \Bigl( \lVert x \rVert^2 e^{\lVert x \rVert^2} \Bigr) = 2x_i e^{\lVert x \rVert^2} + \lVert x \rVert^2 \cdot 2x_i e^{\lVert x \rVert^2} = 2x_i (1 + \lVert x \rVert^2) e^{\lVert x \rVert^2},
$$
and arranging these derivatives in a vector, we find that $\nabla\bigl( \lVert \cdot \rVert^2 e^{\lVert \cdot \rVert^2} \bigr)(x) = 2x(1 + \lVert x \rVert^2) e^{\lVert x \rVert^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider the gradient of the scalar function
$$\eqalign{
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\left(\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\a &= x\cdot x \qiq \grad{\a}{x} = 2x \\
}$$
Then write your function in terms of $\a$ and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
f &= \a e^\a \\
\grad{f}{x}
 &= \gradLR{\a}{x}e^\a+\a \gradLR{e^\a}{x} \\
 &= \left(e^\a\grad{\a}{x}\right) + \a\left(e^\a\grad{\a}{x}\right) \\
 &= (1+\a)\left(e^\a\grad{\a}{x}\right) \\
 &= (1+\a)\left(2e^\a x\right) \\
}$$